# mercurial: apply a bugfix change from stable named branch to dev branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial

i have these two named branches in my repo. Stable and dev. My question is how do i copy a bugfix patch that was changed in stable to the dev branch? i would really like to do this within the framework and not with any extension :)

**EDIT**

I set a bounty for the question because i really wanted the solution. There was a nice solution but was left mid way. So i had no other option. It now appears to have been answered. But i will let the question fair another day, just in case someone has a better solution. Hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: What's the purpose of the bounty?

Comment: see the answers below.. Lesse's answer is close but i think he not available any more. and i really want the an answer.. :) if someone can answer the last couple questions.

Comment: it'd have been cheaper for you to ask particularly him with "@Lesse". He'd be likely to answer.

Comment: yes i know but i am still open to any viable alternatives. Creating a branch jut for a fox is kind of weird.. but  again i am new to version control so i cannot call it just on the basis of my intuition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To augment [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165989/mercurial-apply-a-bugfix-change-from-stable-named-branch-to-dev-branch/7166508#7166508), a different way to approach it is how the Mercurial recommend you do it if you can, plan ahead (I'll see if I can rustle up a link.)

The plan goes that if you know that a bugfix/change has to go into several branches, you don't commit that changeset into one of those places to begin with, you do it somewhere else.

Since you're fixing a bug, somewhere in the history of the project, that bug was introduced.

And since the bugfix needs to go into more than one branch, that "somewhere" has to be before the point where you branched, otherwise the bug wouldn't be in both (/all) branches.

So, the recommended way is to fix the bug where it was introduced, and then merge that changeset into each of the branches that needs it.

Let's look at an example, we have `default` and `stable` branches:

```
1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10       default
         \               \
          \               \
           11--------------12--13            stable
```

Then you discover that changeset 2 introduced a bug, and the bugfix needs to be applied to both `default` and `stable`. The way you describe it in the question, it looks like you would do this:

```
1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10--15       default
         \               \             /^-- merge stable into default
          \               \           /
           11--------------12--13----14          stable
                                     ^-- bugfix
```

But this would merge changeset 13 into `default` as well. If you don't want that to happen, you would instead do this:

```
       v-- bugfix
       14--------------------------+--+
      /                            |   \
     /                             |    \
1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9--x-10--15       default
         \               \         |     ^-- merge 14 into default
          \               \        |
           11--------------12--13--16             stable
                                   ^-- merge 14 into stable
```

For more information on how to use Mercurial in bugfixing-scenarios, the [9th Chapter of 'Mercurial: The Definitive Guide'](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html) is well worth the read.

Comment: so basically you mean i should create a temporary branch which contains the bug fix and then merge it into both dev and stable branch? well that can happen but wont the bugfix branch 'go away' when i merge it with stable? How do i merge a branch which has already been merged? or will the bigfix branch stay unaffected even after merging it to another branch? personally, i was thinking about going with @Tim's third method.

Comment: It won't be a named branch, just an anonymous branch, but it will still be part of your history, and the history will look exactly like I portrayed in the answer. In other words, if you had the exact history as my answer shows, it would look like the final diagram after the merge, it will not "melt into" either branch and disappear.

Comment: cool so the anonymous branch will live on? or do i manually kill it after merging it to other branches? also how exactly do i create such branches?

Comment: In Mercurial branches do not *die*, they may get inactive when merged into another one. Whenever you commit something again at the tip of an inactive branch (eg rev 14 in Lasse's example), it'll get active again.

Comment: ok so i simple create a named branch and that's it? sounds cool.

Comment: After updating to revision 2 (in Lasse's example), you can create a named branch or you can just commit the bugfix and thus create an anonymous branch. If you bookmark the anonymous branch, you have a lightweight alternative to named branches. So, you implicitly create new branches when committing from a non-head revision and it's your decision if you want the branch to be named, bookmarked or anonymous.

Comment: hmm alright.. that sounds good enough :D thanks a ton for joining the dots for me :)

Comment: I've done this and it worked fine. Went back to a feature branch, made a fix, merged it with the last commit of that branch. Merged the result to default and to the current feature branch I'm working on. It just looks a bit awkward, there were about 150 commits since the introduction of the bug.

Answer (score 5):

If your `dev` branch is a descendant of your "stable named branch", then you could simply

```
hg update dev
hg merge stable
```

If this is not feasible, then the most natural answer is the [`transplant` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension).  This extension is distributed with Mercurial, so you only need to add a single line to your `mercurial.ini` or `.hgrc` to enable it.  With it enabled, you can:

```
hg update dev
hg transplant --log <rev>
```

If you *really* want to avoid using an extension, then you could use [`export`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/export) and [`import`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/import):

```
hg export --rev <rev> > tmp.patch
hg update dev
hg import tmp.patch
```

Comment: export or import seems to be it, but i should first check out the extension if it really is a one liner.. Thanks, will comment back if needed :)

Comment: ok so for extension, do i need to mention which branch to copy the `<rev>` should it be something on the lines of `hg up stable` and then `hg transplant --log <rev> -b dev`?

Comment: If you transplanting a single changeset, then `-b` is not needed.  You would use `-b` if you want to transplant all changesets from a branch.  If you specify both `-b` and `<rev>`, then it will transplant all changesets from the branch up to `<rev>`.  I suggest you carefully read `hg help transplant`.

Comment: ah, oh okeez.. yes i read that but clearly, i need to read more :)

Answer (score 0):

[Transplant extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) do the trick nicely - and exactly that you want